HttpClient keep alive past forced idle timeout
I have API A calling API B.
API B takes a lot of time to complete (5+mn)
During that time, there are no traffic between the twos.
Between them, I have a F5 appliance with a 300s idle timeout. Not configurable for security reasons.
While API B will continue its work, I can not get the results since the connection was ended by the F5.
If I use the same HttpClient instance used to call API B to send OPTIONS or get something from API B every X seconds / make noise on the connection, will it maintain the connection past the 300s ?
I'm not sure how HttpClient would behave in such a case.

If your API call takes that long you should rather think about some sort of asynchrounous API if you at least control the APIs instead of allowing extremly long runnning Http calls. The client itself has already a 100 sec timeout you presumably have pushed already and the F5 system in between does those timeout also for a reason. Its not there just to anoy you.

APIs for long-running jobs don't work with a single long running request, because these are bad for the server and API themselves, taking resources for long - RAM, sockets, bandwidth, temp files, database locks. HTTP requests are supposed to be short too so all web appliances (servers, firewalls, routers) are configured that way. Change your API to one of the common strategies, eg a call to start a job and polling for its status, use WebSockets, SignalR or gRPC to have the server notify the client when the job is done. Or both - the client will want the results even if it fails over

Another option, especially in an intranet environment or a K8s cluster, is to use a message queue like RabbitMQ to tell another service to do a job and wait for a response message. Libraries like MassTransit, Wolverine, ReBus, NServiceBus and more build on this, allowing you to process messages in Controller-like handlers while taking care of queues, routes, retries etc themselves

Thanks to everyone for their contributions.
Sending stuff to maintain the connection would not work as any new HttpClient would create another TCP connection. The hassle to create code to ping the exact connection was not worth any effort.
Using a message queue was feasible but I found querying the status of B too much for 1 task.
I ended up using Hangfire :

Api A --> Api B --> Hangfire Job Id
Timer in Api A querying Hangfire Job Status in Api B. An event / exception is risen in Api A accordingly.

(Not worth implementing SignalR in my use-case.)


If I use the same HttpClient instance used to call API B to send OPTIONS or get something from API B every X seconds / make noise on the connection, will it maintain the connection past the 300s ?

If you are using the http keep-alive header, it allows a single TCP connection to remain open for multiple HTTP requests/responses.
But sending the http request is still not a good choice, since open a connection and handle the request will still take a lot of resources inside the server.
I suggest you could consider modifying the codes to use a message queue, the API will just handle the request and add the message into a message queue. Then you could write another process to monitor the queue and handle the long time task.
The client could send the request to the API to check the message queue to return the result for the client for that specific task. This will not keep the connection always open which reduce the server resource usage.
